# Error while building OCR

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, ocr

I was trying to build an ocr which can recognize A-Z, a-z, and 0-9.
That is total 62 classes of recognition.
Here is my code:-

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser() #aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png", help="path to output accuracy/loss plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

print("Loading images.....")
data = []
labels = []

imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42) #aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)

data = np.array(data, dtype = "float")/255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 30, width_shift_range = 0.1, height_shift_range = 0.1, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = False, fill_mode = "nearest")

print("Compiling model.....")
model = ConvNet.build(width = 28, height = 28, depth = 3, classes = 62)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

print("Training model.....")
# aug.fit(trainX)
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size = 10), validation_data = (testX, testY), steps_per_epoch = len(trainX)//10, epochs = 10)

print("Saving the model.....")
model.save(args["model"])
```

When I run this is get the following error:-

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_4 to have shape (None, 62) but got array with shape (853, 1)
```

Please help me understand what is activation_4? and howcome I got an array of shape (843, 1)

This is my code for my ConvNet:-

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras import backend as K

class ConvNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)

        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
        model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(500))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    return model
```

Comment: Most probably, `activation_4` is your last, softmax one - but to be sure, add a `model.summary()` statement just before fitting and include the output here of a *fresh* re-run

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the shape of your network's output and the shape of your labels don't match. As you are using softmax and categorical cross-entropy loss, your labels should be encoded as one-hot vectors.

Fortunately keras provides a method to do this:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
labels = to_categorical(labels)
```

Then if you check the shape of your labels it should be (samples, 62), same as the network output and it should work fine.

Comment: I got the output from the method you said. Thanks. One doubt more please, I had 62 folders for 0-9, A-Z and a-z labelled from 0 to 61. Each folder has 55 samples of images. Can you please tell me how did I get a shape of (853, 1) if I didn't apply one-hot encoding?